# Find $M_{B'}^B(id)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find $M_{B'}^B(id)$. The vector space case is $\mathbb{R}^3$.

$B=\{(1,1,0), (-1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2)\}$

$B'=\{(2,1,1), (0, 0, 1), (-1, 1, 1)\}$

I know the answer is:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3}\\ -1 & 0 & 1 \\ \frac{1}{3} & 1 & \frac{2}{3} \end{bmatrix}$

but I don't see why? Any combination of matrix multiplication doesn't work. So why is this $A=M_{B'}^B(id)$?

$BA\ne B'$

$B^TA\ne B'$

$AB\ne B'$

$AB^T\ne B'$

$B'A\ne B$

$B'^TA\ne B$

$AB'\ne B$

$AB'^T\ne B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a linear map $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and your two bases $B = (b_1,...,b_n),B' = (b'_1,...,b'_n)$, it's always helpful to remind yourself of what an entry in $(a_{ij})_{ij} := A := M_{B'}^B(f)$ stands for. $A$ satisfies

$$f(b_j) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_{ij} b'_i}$$

So what does this tell you? It tells you that **the $j$-th column of $A$ is the image of $b_j$ expressed in coordinates of the basis $B'$**.

Taking your example, (in your case $f=id$) the first vector of $B$ expressed in coordinates of $B'$ is:

$$(1,1,0) = \frac{2}{3} \cdot (2,1,1) + (-1) \cdot (0,0,1) + \frac{1}{3} \cdot (-1,1,1)$$

An we see that $(\frac{2}{3}, -1, \frac{1}{3})$ is the first column of $A$.

This works for the other vectors analogously.

*PS*: A personal note. When I started learning linear algebra in my first semester, understanding what an entry in a matrix where you change bases actually means and stands for, was in my opinion one of the most important lessons. It made many other concepts concerning matrices and linear maps much easier to understand.